# ServiceStack.Razor: Are Layout Files Cached?

Tags: servicestack

I'm having a bit of trouble with the _*Layout.cshtml* file in **ServiceStack.Razor**. I want to show and hide certain links based on whether or not a user is logged in.

What I get from `GetSession<CustomUserSession>()` is different in _*Layout.cshtml* than in *AnyOtherPage.cshtml*. It seems that the layout is getting `new CustomUserSession()` while the pages are getting the correct `CustomUserSession`, but this happens intermittently.

Is the _*Layout.cshtml* cached, or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: I think I am seeing the same thing. Seems like this line is causing it. When the view page is cached userSession has a value and isn't null so the cache is never hit. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Razor/ViewPageBase.cs#L112